# Script não salva palavra completa se tiver acento

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tenho um script que funciona muito bem em meu dashboard, porém coloquei ele em outra página e não está funcionando.

Quando uma palavra tem acento, ex: "Natália" o sistema está salvando no bd apenas "Nat" excluindo o restante que faz parte da palavra.

```
include "painel_dados/bd.php";

// recebendo os dados do formulario
$nome   = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf    = $_POST['cpf'];

$query = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `associados` (`nome`, `cpf`) values (?,?)')or die($mysqli->error);
$query->bind_param('ss', $nome, $cpf);
$query->execute();
```

Onde estou errando?
Se eu der um

> echo $nome;

a palavra aparece certinho. Só na hora de salvar no bd que ela vai incompleta.

Comment: Verifique se o seu banco está com o formato utf-8.

Comment: Está. Descobri o problema. O erro estava na pagina onde tinha o formulário, ela estava em iso

Comment: Ainda bem que vc descobriu porque com o código postado não iríamos descobrir nunca.

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o erro.
A página onde estava o formulário estava com

> charset=iso-8859-1

troquei para

> UTF-8

E funcionou